# SSL programing API

Tags: ssl, tcp, https

I have a packet interface to another entity, not a TCP connection but I need to do SSL on this interface by following SSL over TCP.  Wonder if there is a library that has the following 3 APIs on SSL.  They should be self-evident and they will fit well with the packet interface (not a stream/socket interface).

```
ssl = createSSL();
clearText = fromSSLPipe(ssl, encryptedData, len, &outputLen);
encryptedData = toSSLPipe(ssl, cleartext, len, &outputLen);
```

If there is no such library, could someone give some example(s) on how to implement them?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What platform and language are you using? In general our SecureBlackbox includes SSL/TLS components (both client and server) which are not bound to sockets (you can use absolutely any transport with the components), and it's available for various platforms and languages.

Comment: Can you give a link to some example code?  Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to mention the software is in C and runs on Ubuntu.

Comment: We have some samples, but for C++ edition, I am afraid, only higher-level samples are available (they are included with the evaluation version). For other editions we do have lower-level samples that illustrate how to do what you need.

Comment: Thanks Engene. When we migrate to other platform/languages like Java or golang and we will contact you.

Answer (score 0):

SSL/TLS uses frames with a size of up to 16k. So if this is enough for you, you can simple use SSL_write (will output a single SSL frame if data <16k) and SSL_read (will read single SSL frame and decrypt it) from openssl over a TCP connection. If you need encrypted UDP you can use DTLS, which is also implemented by openssl. While the openssl library is written in C there are interfaces for lots of languages, like perl, python, ruby...

Comment: Frame size doesn't matter - proper SSL/TLS implementation must handle incomplete frames, as TCP is a stream protocol. Early versions of Java had this problem as they expected complete frames to be available in the socket, though.

Comment: If the frame is incomplete it needs to wait for more data, because it can only decrypt full frames. But you are right, that SSL should better be used as a stream protocol, even if SSL_read and SSL_write currently expose the underlying framing.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. The problem here is, there is no tcp socket here.  I need some kind of "primitive" APIs by which I can input x bytes of clear text data, it will output some frames of encrypted data (including signaling frames for SSL handshake). I can send the frames in a different transport (not tcp).

Comment: openssl BIO_* functions will do this, e.g. you don't need a socket but can write on some character buffer with BIO_write and BIO_read. Not as easy as using sockets. Unfortunately the openssl documentation is rough so you need to read lots of openssl source code to understand how all of this fits together :(

Comment: I heard of the BIO_* functions but didn't venture to div into it. I was hoping someone can come up with something simple APIs, such as the ones proposed in the question.   Thanks.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp *Which* early versions of Java had this alleged problem? I was using Java well *before* JSSE appeared, and I never saw any such issue. And a proper TLS/SSL implementation can only handle incomplete *SSL records* by blocking until the complete record arrives.

Comment: probably not. SSL is not only about encrypting and decrypting. You have the initial handshake which does not transfer any payload but where it agrees on crypto algorithms, checks certificate etc. And such handshakes might happen also within an estalished connection. It's more complex than it can be handled with your proposed simple interface.

Comment: @EJP We didn't have such information as the error happened on the remote side and all we could get from the server managers was information that it was Java. But the issue was quite clear - if the packet was sent to the socket with two send() calls (i.e. split in parts), the server didn't work. Combining the packet locally and sending with one send() solved the problem.